# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Python (3.8) platform: run additional pip command for a Python package with `--no-deps` flag aside from using `requirements.txt`

Tags: python, postgresql, pip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

There's this `Python` package called `aiopg` for working with the `PostgreSQL` database asynchronously. It has two dependencies - `async-timeout` and `psycopg2-binary`. I don't want it to install `psycopg2-binary` when using `pip` because I use the regular `psycopg2` package. This is because the authors of `psycopg2-binary` do not recommend using it in production.

This all does not create any problems working locally because I can add the desired dependency of `aiopg` to `requirements.txt` leaving out the undesired one, and then run two separate commands:

1. `pip install -r requirements.txt`
2. `pip install aiopg --no-deps`

But when I push my project to `Elastic Beanstalk` it uses `requirements.txt` to install `Python` packages and I don't know how to run the additional `pip` command.

I tried adding `pip3 install aiopg --no-deps` and also different variations of this command to `eb.config` (both to `commands` and `container_commands` sections) but to no avail.

Right now my `eb.config` looks like so:

```py
packages:
    yum:
        amazon-linux-extras: []

commands:
    01_postgres_activate:
        command: sudo amazon-linux-extras enable postgresql11
    02_postgres_install:
        command: sudo yum install -y postgresql-devel

container_commands:
    01_aiopg_install:
        command: python3 -m pip install aiopg==1.2.1 --no-deps
```

But this is not woking. The Beanstalk environment is in `Severe` state and my `web.stdout.log` still contains this error:
`web: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiopg'`.

So how do I implement this additional `pip` command with `--no-deps` flag which is not supported inside `requirements.txt` files yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had spent a whole day trying to solve this problem before posting this question. But some time after posting this I googled for some more time, tried a couple other approaches and found a working solution.

I changed the last line in my `eb.config` file shown in the question into `command: /var/app/venv/.../bin/python -m pip install aiopg==1.2.1 --no-deps` where `...` should be replaced by the name of the directory sitting inside `/var/app/venv/` in your Beanstalk's EC2 instance. ssh into one of your instances to find this directory or search for `pip` command in your `eb-engine.log` if you set up exporting logs into `CloudWatch` (you'll see the full path to your `pip`'s env there).